# Node.js server only accessible from localhost

Tags: iptables, nodejs

I have an app that is supposed to obtain a string from a server that runs at the local address 192.168.10.10.

The server is a simple nodejs script that looks like this:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('String for App\n');
}).listen(80, "0.0.0.0");
```

When I contact the server as shown below I get the requested string.

```
curl http://localhost:80
```

However, if I try to contact 192.168.10.10 or any other local address it just fails.
What do I need to do to make it work for the IP 192.168.10.10 or even all local IPs?

I am not an expert on any of those things but the netstat output is often requested in similar cases. But as far as I can tell, everything is ok.

```
$ netstat -tulpn
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
...
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
...
```

All scripts run on my Ubuntu 20.04 notebook.
I am not aware of any software that potentially is blocking my requests.

```
$ sudo iptables -L
[sudo] password for xxxx: 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination    

$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Comment: Is ufw activated? You can check via `ufw status`

Comment: It is not activated (sudo ufw status - inactive).